# Extract different paragraphs usins awk

Tags: unix, awk

Suppose I have a large file with different paragraphs

```
> Rosa Luxemburg
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
> Charles Darwin
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
> Charles Chaplin
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
```

And I would like to obtain only the paragraphs with the name Charles (have more than a thousand):

```
> Charles Darwin
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
> Charles Chaplin
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
```

How can do that using awk?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this seems to work, using `>` as new paragraph separator:

```
$ cat file9
> Rosa Luxemburg
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
> Charles Darwin
bbbbb
bbbbbbb
bb
> Charles Chaplin
cccc
ccccc
c
> George Vasiliou
dd
ddddd
dd
dddd

$ awk '/^>/{p=0}/^> Charles/{p=1}p' file9
> Charles Darwin
bbbbb
bbbbbbb
bb
> Charles Chaplin
cccc
ccccc
c
```

Comment: change `/^> Charles/` to `/^>/ && (/Charles/ || /George/)`

Comment: Yep, sorry, because I figured it out!  (I was asking how to extract Charles and George at the same time).

Comment: Rather than testing `^>` twice: `awk /^>/{p=/Charles/}p` file`

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks Ed for this tip. This idiomatic syntax you advised is hilarious. Thank you for sharing.